# How to prove that each tree has at least one leaf on the part with bigger size?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, bipartite-graphs

We know each tree is a bipartite graph. How do you prove that each tree has at least one leaf on the part with bigger size?

Any hints how to start the proof?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Try the contrapositive: if you have a bipartite graph, and if all the vertices in the part with the bigger size have degree greater or equal than two, then you must get a cycle, i.e. not a tree.